# Undesired shaded area when exporting NVD3 line chart to PNG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am new to NVD3. I have created a line chart in nvd3. I haven't set the area attribute in data to 'true' in line chart.However when I export the line chart to PNG,the line chart shows a shaded region in the PNG while there is no shaded region in the actual line chart visualization.I tried putting "area:false" in data used by line chart but it worked the reverse and displayed shaded area in actual line chart.Also,a dark background is dispalyed which isn't present in actual visualization and i believe because of that no axes/lines are visible.How to correct this in exported PNG of the line chart. How to get rid of this shaded area in the exported PNG of the line chart visualization?
The actual visualization looks like this:
[image: Displayed line chart]
The downloaded PNG looks like this
[image: Downloaded PNG]
My current code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="../build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="../build/nv.d3.js"></script>


        <style>
            text {
                font: 12px sans-serif;
            }
            svg {
                display: block;
            }
            html, body, #chart1, svg {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .dashed {
                stroke-dasharray: 5,5;
            }
        </style>
         <script type="text/javascript">

        function download()
        {


    img = new Image(),
            serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
            svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(document.getElementById('svg'));

        img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(svgStr);

        // You could also use the actual string without base64 encoding it:
        //img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + svgStr;

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        var w=3000;
        var h=3000;

        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img,0,0,w,h);

        var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
        dlLink.download = "image";
        dlLink.href = imgURL;
        dlLink.dataset.downloadurl = ["image/png", dlLink.download, dlLink.href].join(':');

        document.body.appendChild(dlLink);
        dlLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(dlLink);



        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body >

    <div id="chart1" width="100%" height='100%'></div>
    <button onclick="download()">Download</button>

    <script>


    var data = [{"color":"#a215af","key":"products","values":[
        {"y":0,"x":0},
        {"y":0,"x":1},
        {"y":1,"x":2},
        {"y":6,"x":3},
        {"y":2,"x":4},
        {"y":0,"x":5},
        {"y":13,"x":6}]}] 

    nv.addGraph(function() {
            chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .options({
                    transitionDuration: 300,
                    useInteractiveGuideline: true
                })
            ;;

      var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

      chart.xAxis
        .rotateLabels(-45)
        .tickValues([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
        .tickFormat(function(d){
          return days[d]
        });


     chart.yAxis
                .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
                .tickFormat(function(d) {
                    if (d == null) {
                        return 'N/A';
                    }
                    return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
                });


     d3.select('#chart1').append('svg')
                .datum(data)
                .attr("id","svg")
                .attr("height","1000")
                .attr("width","1000")
                .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      return chart;
    });



    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems D3 can't render external styles while exporting to canvas. So provide inline styles before downloading.

In your case add these lines of code before accessing SVG element with document.getElementById("svg");

```
d3.selectAll(".c3-axis path").style({ 'fill':'none', 'stroke': '#000' });
d3.selectAll(".c3-chart path").style({ 'fill':'none'});
d3.selectAll(".c3 line").style({ 'fill':'none'});
```

By default, D3 sets style **fill:'none'** in external CSS but while exporting svg element you have to manually provide it in inline as shown above.

**Reference** http://codingquestion.blogspot.com/2016/06/exporting-c3js-line-charts-to-png.html

Answer (score 0):

from the html2canvas [FAQ](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html) we know that it cannot properly deal with svg.

i have very similar requirement and "[example of how to export a png directly from an svg](http://bl.ocks.org/deanmalmgren/22d76b9c1f487ad1dde6)" solved my problem (internally it adopted [svg-crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) code). basically, you need to draw the svg to a canvas then export the image to png, and "explicitly set css style" for all svg element is the caveat to make the exported image like original - and it is the problem you have experienced.